# How to migrate data from mongodb to mysql?

Tags: mysql, mongodb

I am currently working on an application like to analitics, i has **Angularjs app** which communicates with **Spring REST Client App** from which user creates token(trackingID) and use generated script with this id putting on his website to collect information about visitor's actions through another **Spring REST tracking App**, for **tracking app** i am using as mongodb to collect visitor actions/visitor info for fast insertion, but for **rest client app** mysql with user/accounts details.
My question is how to migrate mongo data from tracking app to mysql maybe for getting posibility of join for easily and fastest way of analyze data with any kind of filters from angularjs client app, to create manually any workers that periodically will transfer data from last point to present state from mongo to mysql, or are any existed tools that can be setted for this transfer?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

There is no official library to do this.
But you can use `mongoexport` feature from mongoDB to export it in a CSV format and `mysqlimport` to import them into MySQL.

Here are links to the documentation [MySQL import](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysqlimport.html) and [MongoDB Export](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/program/mongoexport/#export-in-csv-format).

One more method you can try to write a program in one of your favorite language and read from MongoDB and write into MySQL

Comment: However this method does not consider nested documents.

Comment: @Michael as it is not general that where the nested document should be in a table, it is better to use the second method I mentioned of writing a program to do that, where you can specify mapping of mongodb fields to mysql fields

Answer (score 9):

MySQL 5.7 has a new JSON data type, that can be very convenient.

You can create a table at MySQL to receive the JSON messages AS IS, and then use SQL to query it or do a post processing to load the data in a structured set of database tables.

Check this out: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json.html

Answer (score 6):

I realise this question is a few years old - but recently I've had a number of people enquiring whether a [tool I developed](https://virtual.blue/apps/json-converter) (https://virtual.blue/apps/json-converter) can do exactly what the OP is asking (convert MongoDB to SQL) so I am guessing it is still something people want. Keep reading to find out why I am honestly not surprised by this.

The short answer to whether the tool can help you is: perhaps. If your existing data relationships are not too complicated, and your database is not enormous, it may well be worth a try.

However, I thought it might help to try and explain what the issues are with this kind of conversion, since all the answers I have seen so far are along the lines of "try tool X" or "first convert to format Y and then you can slurp it into MySQL using utility Z". ie there is no thought to whether what you get at the end of doing this is going to make sense in terms of data relationships and integrity.

For example, you could just stick your entire database dump in a single field of a single SQL table (ok space limitations might prevent this in reality, but hopefully you get my point). Then your database would be "in MySQL format", but it would be absolutely no use to anyone.

The point is, what you actually want is a fully defined database model, correctly encapsulating all of the intrinsic data relationships. ("[Database normalization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization)" as it is known.) If your conversion process gets those relationships wrong, then you have a broken model, and any queries you try to run over it are likely to return nonsense. Unfortunately there is no magic tool that is just going to "know" the best way to represent your data in MySQL, and closing your eyes and shovelling it into a bunch of random tools is unlikely to miraculously get you what you want.

And herein lies the fundamental problem with the "NoSQL" philosophy (fad). They sold people the bogus notion of "non-relational data". My first thought when I heard this was, "How does that work? Surely *all* data is relational?" By the looks of things we are steadily getting more and more evidence that my instincts were right. ("NoSQL? Why stop there? I go with 'NoDatabase'. It returns no results at all, but it sure is fast!")

The NoSQL madness throws several important fundamental engineering principles to the wind. We shouted "don't hard code!", "DRY!" (Don't Repeat Yourself) because these actions infuse inflexibility into systems. Traditional wisdom makes precisely the same flexibility argument when it advises "create a fully described model with all the data relationships represented". Then you can execute any arbitrary query over it and expect meaningful results. "Yes but there are a whole bunch of queries we are never going to need to run," says the NoSQL proponent. But surely we learnt our lesson on things we are "never going to need to do"? ("I hard code liberally, because I know I am never going to want to change my code." Hmm...)

The arguments about speed are largely moot. Say it turns out you are frequently doing a complex 9 table join, with unsurprisingly sluggish performance. So create an index. Cache it. Swap some disk space for speed. The NoSQL philosophy is to swap data integrity for speed, which makes no sense at all.

When you generate your fast lookup index (cache/table/map/whatever) what you are really doing is creating a view over your model. If your model changes, you can readily update your view. Going from a model to a view is easy - it's a one to many operation and you are on the right side of entropy.

However, when you went with MongoDB you effectively decided to create views without bothering to describe your fundamental model. Now you discover there are queries you want to run, but can't - and so it's no wonder you want to move over to SQL and actually have your data modelled correctly. The problem is you now want to go from a view to a model. Now you're on the wrong side of entropy. Your view is a lossy representation of the model's fundamental relationships. You can't expect a tool to "translate" your database, because you are asking it to insert new relationships which were not originally defined. These are real world relationships that are not machine-guessable. The tool cannot know what relationships were intended.

In short the only way you can do this reliably is to get your hands dirty. An intelligent human, with complete understanding of the system you are modelling needs to sit down and carefully come up with (possibly a substantial amount of) code which effectively picks through the data and resolves all of the insufficiently represented data relationships. If your data is complex then it's going to be a headache and there is no way to cheat.

If your data is still relatively simple then I would suggest making the conversion as soon as possible, before it becomes difficult. In this case my tool (https://virtual.blue/apps/json-converter) may be able to help.

(They really should have asked a Physicist before they came up with all this nonsense...!)

Comment: It is nice to know that I am not alone in thinking like you do. I am looking at the exact concept you describe.  I walked into it thinking, "What no problem". No I am wading deeply into the muck. Normalization was not an easy thing for me to grasp. I was flummoxed when I started reading about NoSQL. 

Then I started seeing weird things. Finding something I posted on facebook years ago involved me scrolling through pages. I couldn't just search. 

But text files are pretty fast to load. What is JSON but a text file.

Comment: It is like you have read my mind and experienced all that I have. Thank you for this comment. NoSQL is a trap for anything but the most basic toy apps or trivially simplistic data models. Trivially simplistic data models ARE common though, and in those cases the speed of NoSQL can be a win... I just don't actually see very many actual use cases like that in real life VS the weight of the hype surrounding NoSQL. It never really added up, which has to make you consider if it was the technology that was amazing, or the marketing.

Answer (score 2):

You can download a trial version of Studio 3T for Mongo and export your database to SQL (or JSON) directly